# Lua arithmetic on string variable

Tags: lua

I have this small snippet of code here;

```
for i=1,1000 do
    n=math.floor(math.sin(i/10.0)*40)
    s=''
    for j=1,n do s=s+'-' end
    print(s)
end
```

But it gives me an error on line 2: "attempt to perform arithmetic on global 's' (a string value)" I don't know why it's doing this, and it's driving me mad.

Comment: Use `string.rep` instead of the inner for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike some other languages, Lua uses `..` to concatenate strings, not `+`, change

```
s = s + '-'
```

to

```
s = s .. '-'
```

Answer (score 1):

A loop of string concatenations is not recommended because it leads to a quadratic copy (not that it matters for small strings). Try `string.rep` instead.

```
for i=1,1000 do
    n=math.floor(math.sin(i/10.0)*40)
    print(string.rep('-',n))
end
```